# MSXML getElementsByTagName() does not work with any TagName

Tags: xml, msxml, getelementsbytagname

i use MSXML getElementsByTagName("TagName") to read out an XML file. It works fine in most caes.

However I can not read some fields.

A sample xml file i use can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/idBTN5Vb

When I read out the nodes "AreaPercent", it works fine.
When I want to read the nodes "Area" (e.g. line 81 in that file) it does not work.

I could imagine this has something to do with the below node:
    66.364914
that is named area as well.

So my question: How to read out the nodes "Area" in this file?.
If any more info is needed, just ask.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "I could imagine this has something to do with the below node: 66.364914 that is named area as well."
this came out wrong via pasting.
I mean e.g. line 164 in that xml file. Those nodes have the name "Area" as well.

Comment: Ok the problem is solved.
Don't know what the problem caused, however :(.